# Need to check connection every method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, ssh

I need to implement a Linux file utility class with SSH as below:

```
class LinuxFileOperation
{
    private string ip, username, password;

    public LinuxFileOperation(string ip, string username, string password)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void CopyFileOnDevice(string remoteFileNameToBeCopied, string remoteFileNameToBePasted)
    {
        using (var sshClient = new SshClient(ip, username, password))
        {
            sshClient.RunCommand($"cp {remoteFileNameToBeCopied} {remoteFileNameToBePasted}");
        }
    }

    public void DeleteFile(string remoteFilePath)
    {
        using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(ip, username, password))
        {
            sftpClient.DeleteFile(remoteFilePath);
        }
    }

    public bool FileExists(string file)
    {
        using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(ip, username, password))
        {
            var fileAttr = sftpClient.GetAttributes(file);
            return fileAttr.IsRegularFile;
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetFileList(string fullSearchPath)
    {
        using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(ip, username, password))
        {
            return sftpClient.ListDirectory(fullSearchPath).Select(s => s.FullName).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Almost every methods with the same code **using (var sftpClient/sshClient = new SftpClient/SshClient(ip, username, password))**.
Any pattern would reduce the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
class LinuxFileOperation
{

    private T WithClient<T>(Func<SftpClient, T> action)
    {
        using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(ip, username, password))
        {
            return action(sftpClient);
        }
    }

    public bool FileExists(string file)
    {
        return WithClient(client => client.GetAttributes(file).IsRegularFile);
    }
}
```

... although it doesn't reduce the line count that much.

You can also make use of using declarations:

```
class LinuxFileOperation
{

    private sftpClient CreateClient() => new SftpClient(ip, username, password)[

    public bool FileExists(string file)
    {
        using var client = CreateClient();
        return client.GetAttributes(file).IsRegularFile;
    }
}
```